# Second part of code works earlier then the first part

Tags: javascript

I have a tag list which saved in an object. I want it to give an error message when tag list is empty.  Altough the checking part of code is beeing end of the code, it works before.

```
 $("#Save").click(function(e){
    var size = 0;
    tagArray = new Array;
    for (key in tagObjectList )
    {
        tagArray.push(tagObjectList[key].toString());
        console.log(key);
        ++size;
        alert(size); //it's displayed after below alert. diplays  1,2,...,tag count
    }

    alert(size); // displays 0. ???
    if (size == 0) {
        alert("There is no tag!");
        return false;
}
    $("#tagData").val('[' + tagArray.toString() + ']');
});
```

What is wrong here? Could you help me please?

Comment: This works for me. I don't see any way how `size` could have been reset. Can you show a demo?

Comment: Your code pasted and then proprietary elements taken out. Works fine. There must be more to your code than you're showing here: http://jsfiddle.net/Wh2NZ/

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fine, so make sure you don't have a more than one element with same `#Save` id, because that would cause your click handler to be executed twice, so mixing `alerts()` from both executions.

That could be an explanation for the problem you're seeing.

Comment: When I inspect it with debugger, I realized that the click fuction is called two times. But how this could be happen?

Comment: The most probably because you have more than one element with `id=Save`, but if you posted the full html+javascript we would better tell it.

Comment: I have 2 submit button but theri id's different. is it cause this problem. $form['upload'] = array
 (
  '#type' => 'submit',
     "#id" => 'Upload',
  '#value' => t('Upload'),
  '#submit' => array(),
  '#ahah' => array
  (
   'path' => 'addnewnode',
   'wrapper' => 'ahah-new-row-wrapper',
   'method' => 'replace',
   'effect' => 'fade',
   'progress' => array('type' => 'bar', 'message' => t('Please wait...')),
       'event' => 'click',
  ),
 );

 $form['submit'] = array
 (
  '#type' => 'submit',
     "#id" => 'Save',
     '#value' => t('Save'),
     '#suffix' => '</div>'
 );